# Trouble scraping some sites with PHP and curl

Tags: php, node.js, curl, web-scraping, request

I would say I am fairly experienced in scrpaing web sites - Mostly I have used PHP and the curl library and have overcome lots of problems.

My normal process:

1. Load request in chrome
2. Copy request as curl from Network tab
3. Paste into Postman
4. click Code and export the code.

Normally this will work, and if it doesnt, within 5 minutes of tweaking cookies, user agents or other headers, I can make the request work.

I have a couple of sites, where I just cant get it work via PHP/Curl, but it *does* work via postman. I have also tried using the *request* library in nodejs and these sites that do not work via PHP/curl, work fine with a default request, such as:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const url = 'https://www.very.co.uk/';

rp(url)
  .then(function(html){
    //success!
    console.log(html);
  })
```

As you can see, i am not setting any special headers, user agent or cookies but this works - so why would this not work in PHP/Curl?

Using some verbose output in PHP/Curl, i have managed to get the following output:

An error occurred: (56) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104

But then why wouldnt I get this nodejs and even if I set the following header:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

This doesnt solve the issue when using PHP/CURL - can you help?

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: My guess is the other software like Postman has a different OpenSSL/Curl version than your PHP. As the error is a connection reset from the remote host there's something in your PHP setup it doesn't like such as requiring a cypher not present. Maybe try upgrading your OpenSSL version or trying to force a TLS 1.2 connection.

Comment: @cOle2 excellent suggestion, thanks - one uses LibreSSL and one uses OpenSSL - testing now to see if I can make it work.